# Garry's Mod MOTD popping up for everybody when a player joins the server

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Upon following a tutorial to set up a basic lobby screen in Garry's Mod, I encountered a bug that makes the lobby screen pop up on everybody's screen every time a player joins.

I'm new to programming, and I am unsure of what to even consider trying.

```
function openLobby()
    local frame = vgui.Create("DFrame")
    frame:SetSize(ScrW(),ScrH())
    frame:Center()
    frame:SetVisible(true)
    frame:ShowCloseButton(false)
    frame:SetDraggable(false)
    frame:SetTitle("")
    frame.Paint = function(s, w, h)

    draw.RoundedBox(0,0,0,w,h,Color(0,0,0,255))

end

frame:MakePopup()

local startBut = vgui.Create("DButton", frame)
startBut:SetSize(200,75)
startBut:SetPos(ScrW()/2 - 100,ScrH()/2 - (75/2))
startBut:SetText("Start Game")

startBut.DoClick = function()
    net.Start("start_game")
    net.SendToServer()

    frame:Close()
end

end

net.Receive("open_lobby",openLobby)
```

I expect to have the "start game" screen pop up upon joining, and never show up again unless the player rejoins, but instead it is popping up every time a player joins.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9OIcalHbqQ&feature=youtu.be

Above is the issue that I am having in video form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function openLobby()
    local frame = vgui.Create("DFrame")
    frame:SetSize(ScrW(), ScrH())
    frame:Center()
    frame:SetVisible(true)
    frame:ShowCloseButton(false)
    frame:SetDraggable(false)
    frame:SetTitle("")

    frame.Paint = function(s, w, h)
        draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, w, h, Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
    end

    frame:MakePopup()
    local startBut = vgui.Create("DButton", frame)
    startBut:SetSize(200, 75)
    startBut:SetPos(ScrW() / 2 - 100, ScrH() / 2 - (75 / 2))
    startBut:SetText("Start Game")

    startBut.DoClick = function()
        net.Start("start_game")
        net.SendToServer()
        frame:Close()
    end
end

hook.Add("InitPostEntity", "onJoinStartGameWindow", function()
    timer.Simple(5, function()
        openLobby()
    end)
end)
```